# spring bean creation for java builder pattern objects

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, gson

I'm using Google Gson(gson) library form reading/writing json files and spring mvc 3 in my web application side.

So In controller, I want to create a singleton instance of Gson with pretty printing. In java the code would be,

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

In Controller, I created an autowired entry as below,

```
@Autowired
private Gson gson;
```

and the xml bean configuration is as below,

```
<bean id="gsonBuilder" class="com.google.gson.GsonBuilder">
         <property name="prettyPrinting" value="true"/>
 </bean>  
 <bean id="gson" factory-bean="gsonBuilder" factory-method="create"/>
```

It throws the following exception in catalina logs,

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'prettyPrinting' of bean class [com.google.gson.GsonBuilder]: Bean property 'prettyPrinting' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1024)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:900)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
```

I knew that the setter signature of setPrettyPrinting() is different than spring expects, that's why spring is throwing the exception.

```
  public GsonBuilder setPrettyPrinting() {
    prettyPrinting = true;
    return this;
  }
```

But I'm unable to find a way to wire the builder pattern beans. I'm pretty new to spring. Can any one let me know, whether it is possible to solve this problem in xml bean approach ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use a static factory method as described [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method) and use Java code to create Java objects: it's sooo much easier and safe:

```
<bean id="gson"
      class="com.foo.bar.MyGsonFactory"
      factory-method="create"/>
```

and in MyGsonFactory:

```
public static Gson create() {
    return new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The setPrettyPrinting method doesn't take a parameter, so it doesn't look like a java bean property setter. That's why your approach didn't work. You can use the factory method mentioned in the other answer or use a [method invoking bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingBean.html) in the config file like so:

```
 <bean id="myStarter" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingBean">
   <property name="targetObject" ref="gsonBuilder"/>
   <property name="targetMethod" value="setPrettyPrinting"/>
 </bean>
```

The factory approach seems more straightforward and idiomatic to me, but I include this approach for the sake of completeness.

Comment: 1 Upvote for  suggesting the MethodInvokingBean approach. I never knew of this approach

Comment: Also if any one wants xml configuration only, they can use this approach. I liked it.